# Como paso un archivo como argumento a una funcion?

Tags: c++, array, fstream

Me gustaría saber como pasar un archivo como argumento .
por ejemplo si tengo un archivo "data" lo tengo que pasar como la variable  `miArchivo` (como en el programa que puse de ejemplo abajo) ?

```
//Contenido del archivo data es:1 2 3 4 5 

// Asi que el programa deberia de simplemente guardar los numeros del uno al cinco
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void leer_array( int num [], int );//como hago para que esta funcions lea los contenidos del archivo en el array.

int main() {

  const int TAMAÑO = 5;
  int numeros[] = {0,0,0,0,0};


  ifstream miArchivo;
  miArchivo.open("data");     //abriendo archivo data

  leer_array(num[] , TAMAÑO);  //llamando a la funcion


  miArchivo.close();


  return 0;


}


void leer_array( int num [], int tamaño){ //esta es la funcion deberia leer archivos en el array

  int i = 0 , index;

  while ( i < tamaño && miArchivo >> num[i]){

    i++;

  }

  for(index = 0; index < tamaño ;index++ ){

    cout<< num [index] << " " ;

  }


}
```

muchas gracias a todos los que respondan.

edito : solucionado

```
  ifstream miArchivo;
  miArchivo.open("data");

  //esas dos lineas tenian que estar dentro de la funcion ,y 
  //no se pueden pasar como parametro.
```

De hecho buscando en internet encontre que puedes usar "ifstream& inputFile" como tercer parametro.
entonces si es posible pasarlo como argumento despues de todo.

Comment: ¿Acaso no puedes pasar la ruta del archivo?

Comment: no se exactamente a lo que te refieres , pero el ejemplo es suponiendo que el archivo  data funciona y  si es leido normalmente .solo me gustaria saber especificamente que es lo que tengo que pasar como tercer parametro . gracias por  comentar.

Comment: Me refiero a que no necesitas pasar un archivo como parámetro, esa posibilidad no existe (un archivo es un elemento "físico" en el disco duro, no un dato); lo que si puedes hacer es pasar la ruta al archivo y abrirlo+procesarlo dentro de la función `leer_array`.

Comment: oh ya te entendi muchas gracias !  solo queria estar seguro de saber si se podia pasar el archivo al parametro. pero ya me funciono haciendo lo que me dijiste, puse el ifstream adentro de la funcion. gracias